# Printing out double quote in Python have space

Tags: python, space, double-quotes

```
print('"',*x,'"')
```

Gives out

```
" Hello world "
```

I desire

```
"Hello world"
```

What should I do?

Comment: `print('"' + ' '.join(x) + '"')`

Comment: or `print(f'"{" ".join(x)}"')`

Comment: The `print` function adds spaces inbetween all individual strings it has to print. You'll have to combine the different pieces into a single string before passing it to `print`.

Comment: Or use `sep=""` as it defaults to space. `print('"',*x,'"', sep="")`

Comment: @DavidBuck No, that will print `"Helloworld"`. Note that `x` is iterable.

Comment: @BoseongChoi - OP didn't tell us what `x` is. If `x="Hello World"` it works just fine.

Comment: @DavidBuck No, If `x="Hello World"`, then it should be `" H e l l o   W o r l d "` original output.

Comment: Not with `sep=""`. I do get your point,  and I'm sure you're probably quite correct, but for all we know x might be `x = ["Hello", " ", "World"]`. The OP's question lacks clarity.

Comment: @DavidBuck I agree with you. I think OP should specify what `x` is.

Answer (score 1):

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) put spaces(`' '`) between each arguments. You can change that with `sep=` keyword argument, but then you can't have space for between `x`'s elements. So you can add spaces manually.

```py
x = ['Hello', 'world']

print(f'"{" ".join(x)}"')  # Python 3.6 or later only
print('"' + " ".join(x) + '"')
print('"{}"'.format(' '.join(x)))
```

output:

```
"Hello world"
"Hello world"
"Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `sep` parameter.

```
print('"', *x, '"', sep = '')
```

Comment: Then, `"Helloworld"` will be printed.

Comment: sep parameter works when you are printing several strings, so I think this was a good response